# how to retrive the value of shared preference for checking the condition

Tags: java, android

here I have three buttons Yes no maybe for three buttons I have changed the colour when the button clicked and store the value of clicked button in shared preference for hold the colour when ever I back to the button

@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation, null);
        eventNameTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_title);
        eventPlaceTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_place);
        eventNameTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getText());
        eventPlaceTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getPlace());

        convertView.setTag(position);
        View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

        final Button yesBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yesbutton);
        final Button noBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nobutton);
        final Button maybeBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonmaybe);


        final LinearLayout eventLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);


        final LinearLayout responseLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);

        //Based on the user click, response will be stored



        yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // highlight the button when clicked
                yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //If user clicks yes button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 1 for event user
                final int response = 1;
                final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
                userMO.setIsAttending(response);
                //create shared preferences here

                prefs =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor =prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("buttonClicked","true");
                editor.commit();

                /*SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("clicked_btn", 1);
                editor.commit();*/
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                    }

                }.execute(null, null, null);

            }

        });

        noBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //If user clicks no button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 0 for event user
                final int response = 0;
                final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
                userMO.setIsAttending(response);

                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("clicked_btn", 0);
                editor.commit();

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                    }

                }.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        });
        maybeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //If user clicks maybe button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as  for event user
                final int response = 2;
                userMO.setIsAttending(response);
                final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();

                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("clicked_btn",2);
                editor.commit();

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                    }

                }.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        });
```

here I have to hold the colour change of button whenever I return back to the app if I selected any of the button .so how to use and retrieve the shared preference value

this is the code for show the yes no maybe buttons together when I clicked the event

```
eventLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                                      switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.invitation_single:
                            responseLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;

                    }
                }


           });
```

Comment: give some try http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: So, you would like to store the buttons color in your preferences?

Comment: yes and I hold the color of the button for ever if I already selected that button

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` gives you the ability to store different kind of data, such as `boolean` or `int`.

To accomplish your task, you could store the color of each button in `SharedPreferences`; something like:

```
 editor.putInt("button_one", R.color.buttone_one_selected);
```

Remember, when you'll retrieve that color, you have to resolve it with:

```
int buttonOneColor = sharedPrefs.getInt("button_one", default_value); 
int colorBackground = getResources().getColor(buttonOneColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change color of your button using this...

In onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

now check for the boolean value stored in the preferences :

```
boolean b1_pressed = prefs.getBoolean("button1_pressed",false);

if(b1_pressed){

//code to change color of button to pressed state

}

else{

//code to change color of button to normal state

}
```

Now in your button's onClick method:

```
if(b1_pressed){

SharedPreferences.editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putBoolean("button1_pressed",false);

editor.commit();

}
else{

SharedPreferences.editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putBoolean("button1_pressed",true);

editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: am I want to create variable and if condition for every button

Comment: How many buttons are you using??And what about the statuses for all the button is it same or different for every button....If all status are same or co-related you can use just one if else statement and perform color change for all buttons....

Comment: here I have used 3 buttons . I used this method its working but first I clicked yes button it colours changed and next I clicked no button here that yes button should be back to normal and now no button colour should change here when I clicked another button the first button hold that colour

Comment: Change colors on every buttons' onClick() method then....like for yes button color set yes button's color to selected and other buttons' color to normal....and do the same no and maybe button....